# Validate different date formats in C#

Tags: c#, regex, date, datetime

This Question may sound silly but I tried in all the different ways I can as I want to validate different formats of date or date-time and log the error if the format is invalid.

```
Example: 10 March 2016, 10 Mar 16, 10 Mar 2016
```

I tried using regular expression but it just checks for normal date, date-time formats say `DD/MM/YYYY`, `YYYY/MM/DD`, `DD-MM-YYYY` etc.

Here is my code:

```
bool isDate = Regex.IsMatch(Value.ToString(), @"^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$");

if (isDate == true)
{
     DateTime datetime;
     DateTime.TryParse(Value.ToString(), out datetime);
     sGetDate = datetime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
     GetString.Add(sName + ":" + sGetDate);
}
else{
    //log error
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this? Cheers.

Comment: Why not just use `DateTime.TryParse` as a first validation? Of course, it will parse integers (e.g., 42) but you can easily check against this as well.

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? Detect the format?

Comment: Yes, I want to detect the format and validate as well.

Comment: I used         DateTime.Tryparse          but I dont know how to detect the date format like "20 Mar 2016".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is seems, you have no need in *regular expressions*: try parsing and see if it succeeds:

```
  string source = "10 Mar 16";

  ...

  // Put all allowed formats here 
  string[] formats = new string[] {
    "d MMMM yyyy",
    "d MMM yyyy",
    "d MMM yy"
  };

  if (DateTime.TryParseExact(source, 
                             formats, 
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, //TODO: may be you want CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
                             DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, 
                             out datetime)) {
    // datetime contains valid date and time 
  }
  else {
   // log error: parsing fails
  }
```

Comment: I tried with that first and that didn't work for me, Can you help me if you got any?

Comment: `InstalledUICulture` is almost definitely wrong. First of all, this is the *UI* language, thus should have no bearing on formatting dates. Second, it's the culture in which the OS was installed originally, which is not necessarily the one the user is using. You'd want `CurrentCulture` instead (if the user's one should be used), or an explicit one (if the application expects a very specific one).

Comment: @pavan: I'm sorry for the typo. It should be either  `InvariantCulture` or `CurrentCulture`.

Comment: @Joey: Nice catch! Thank you! I'm sorry for the typo (I tried to put `InvariantCulture` with comment, but miswrote)

Comment: @pavan: you're welcome! Once again, I'm sorry for the typo.